# htaccess redirect all pages without homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this htaccess code which redirect entire site to other.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It redirects my entire website and homepage. How can I specify the pages who i want to not redirect?

Thank you sooooo much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some conditions:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo.bar$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

etc.